# Save json api results to json file in newline delimited format using php

Tags: php, json, laravel, google-bigquery, ndjson

I am getting a nested json object back from an api call and I am trying to save it to a newline delimited json file so it can be imported into Google Big Query.

Here is what I have and it saves it to my file but still not correctly formatted for Big Query to import it.

```
    $response = $this->client->post($url);

    $results = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents());
    $date = Carbon::now()->toDateString();

    $filename = 'resources/results-' . $date . '.ndjson';

    foreach ($results as $result) {
        $newline = json_encode($result) . "\n";
        file_put_contents(base_path($filename), $newline, FILE_APPEND);
    }
```

I have also just tried to save the json to a file but get same error when trying to import to big query.

Comment: What error you get?

Comment: Error while reading data, error message: Failed to parse JSON: No object found when new array is started.; BeginArray returned false; Parser terminated before end of string

Comment: Try to debug the response, it seems like json returned fom API is not correct.

`$body = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
dd($body);
`
Passing 3rd params as true will make `array` not object.

Comment: I get a nested array that goes 4 levels deep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pass true value to second parameter of json_decode() method to return associate array like this:

```
  $results = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(),true);
```